# When a subclass is instantiated, is only one object created?

Tags: java, object

Since many constructors also call the superclass constructor, it seems like one could think that both the subclass and the superclass are instantiated when a subclass is instantiated; i.e. more than one object is created.

Is still just one object created?

Thank you

Comment: When a Human is born an new Mammal is also created but only one object. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just one object, even if the super's constructor is called you are just performing additional instantiation on the one object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes only one object is created

Answer (score 1):

Just one object is created in memory.

Answer (score 1):

At least one object is created.  Who knows how many objects are created in the constructor?

```
class X extends Y
{
    Object [ ] objects ;

    X ( int n )
    {
         super ( ) ;
         objects = new Object [ n ] ;
         for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++ )
         {
              objects [ i ] = new Object ( ) ;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Einstein is attributed a saying: explanations should be as simple as possible, but no simpler. The simple answer 'only one object' may be perhaps true, but misses a lot of important information.

As Nick asked, we can invoke the superclass constructor. So that the superclass constructor is 'somewhere', even though I instantiated only the subclass. Is easy to reason that the instance of the subclass must include all the members of the superclasses (all of them, up to Object). In principle all this pile of variables and methods is the subclass instance. These variables and methods must include also variables not inherited by the subclass. So that the instance is not just what the subclass declares or inherits. I.e. a Cat is-a Mammal, even if Mammal declares some member that Cat doesn't inherit (a poor Java design decision, IMO).

For example, if the superclass has a private variable 'priv', and public accessors getPriv() setPriv(), subclass can invoke the accessors, therefore accessing the variable, modifying state, etc. Yet 'priv' itself is not anywhere to be found in the subclass .class file. So that there is more to the instance than 'just the class'.

I leave to some other discussion the rationale behind 'subclass doesn't inherit private members, etc.'. Never made any sense to me (the instance variables are this instance's; so what access control are you talking about? an object can't access its own parts?! ... anyways ... that was the designers decision)

BTW the JVM spec says nothing (and indeed, shouldn't say anything) about how to implement the inheritance semantics. One possible solution (which may or may not be what any of the JVMs do) would be to create full instances of all the ancestor classes when an instance of the subclass is created. Why not?. It is unlikely anyone will come with an authoritative source declaring that this shall not be done. Certainly the JVM spec doesn't say that.

If someone can contribute a pointer to actual JVM implementation information on this topic, that would be illuminating. I couldn't find it by google'ing. Neither could find an authoritative confirmation of the 'just one object' assertion. May be. I don't know. Conceptually, as a Java language construct? sure! but with 'clarifications'. Implementation-wise, i.e. 'in memory'? may be, may be not.

-Polo